# Regex for specific numbers and special characters

Tags: c#

I want to extract the values 9.6%,2021,4th from the below input string and tried with different solutions but not displaying output as expected.
input string: `Gross Domestic Product decreased by 5.9% in volume in the fourth quarter 2021 and by 9.6% in 2021 - 4th Quarter 2021`

```
var pattren = "^-?\\d*(\\.\\d+)?$";
var result  = Regex.Match(s, pattren);
```

Comment: experiment here https://regex101.com/

Comment: start with (\d*\.\d+) in regex101 and take it from there

Comment: Here is a hint and take it from there: `.+\s+(\d+\.\d+\%)\s+|in\s+(\d+)|\-\s+(\d+(st|nd|rd|th)?)\s+.+`

Answer (score 0):

A solution I came up, might not be optimal though, as it takes extra step I think.

1. Get the wanted part by `(\d+\.*\d*%)\s*in\s*(\d{4})\s*-\s*(1st|2nd|3rd|4th)`
2. Since there's a nuance in your question, there're 2 possibilities as the next step:

- `Replace()` `in` and `-` to `,` to get string `"9.6%,2021,4th"`
- `Group` 1,2,3 of the `Match` will be `"9.6%"`, `"2021"` and `"4th"`.

Problem is, dealing with text always has surprises waiting for you. Test for more cases and adjust the method to deal with exceptional inputs.

For reference:

- [String.Replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0)
- [String.Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0)
- [Match.Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?view=net-6.0)